# function with pointer return type is rvalue

Tags: c++

```
struct A {
   char f1() {return *c;} // 1) f1() is rvalue
   char * f2(){return c;}  // 2) f1() is rvalue
   char & f3(){return *c;} // 3) f1() is lvalue
   char * c;
};

int main () {
 char * a = "string"; // 4)  it can be readable, when writed to a, problem will crash, why ?
 const char * ab = "string"; // 5) ab is READ-ONLY
```

}

Questions

a) For line 2) why function with pointer return type is rvalue, not a lvalue ?

b) For line 4) and 5), what is really the type of "string" ? A "const char *" ? More intersting to know, which part of memory it locates in ?

Comment: Your `f1()` lacks a dereference.

Comment: Too many questions in one.

Answer (score 3):

> why function with pointer return type is rvalue, not a lvalue ?

Because a pointer is an object, and the result of a function call is always an *rvalue* if the return type is an object type. Dereferencing the pointer will give an *lvalue* denoting the object it points to.

> when writed to a, problem will crash, why ?

Because string literals are `const`, and writing to them gives undefined behaviour. In modern C++, there's no implicit conversion to non-const `char*`, so your example wouldn't compile. Historically, that dodgy conversion was allowed for arcane reasons. I suggest you consider using a more up-to-date compiler, specifying C++11 or C++14 as the language dialect, to prevent this nastiness. At the very least, enable compiler warnings.

> what is really the type of `"string"` ?

An array of constant characters, large enough for the characters in the string literal plus a zero terminator. In this case, `char const[7]`.

> More intersting to know, which part of memory it locates in ?

String literals are constant, and have static storage duration, so are typically stored in a read-only data segment. It's unspecified whether two literals with the same value refer to the same static array, or two separate ones.

Comment: Historically: K&R required string literals to be writable.  Someone on the C standardization committee apparently felt that having `"string"` actually be `"xxxxxx"` was not conducive to readable code, and made modifying them undefined behavior (without changing the type from `char[]`).  That was some time in the late 1980's, though.  C++ (mid-1990's) changed the type to `char const[]`, but with a special conversion rule to avoid breaking things like `char* p = "hello";`; I'm not sure, but I think this special conversion has since been removed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, the (previously deprecated) conversion was removed in C++11. Thanks for filling in the historical details I glossed over.

Comment: Yes.  I was fairly active in C++98, and I remember the discussions.  We adopted a couple of features which were deprecated from the start so that 1) we could hopefully remove them in the future, and 2) to encourage compilers to start warning about them immediately.  (The two I remember were this conversion and incrementing a `bool`.)

Answer (score 1):

a)line 2 return back some rvalue in type (char*).It is rvalue of (char*).char* is just a type like int or char.in line 3 it is lvalue because there is (char&) and it sends back the reference(lvalue) .

b)"string" is a const char* variable because of that you cannot read or write with char* ,if you try , you trigger undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
char f1() {return *c;} // 1) f1() is rvalue
```

*c is the value the pointer c is pointing to

```
 char * f2(){return c;}  // 2) f1() is rvalue
```

f2() now points to the address pointed by c, that is now *f2() holds the value pointed to by c.

Answer (score 1):

> when writed to a, problem will crash, why ?

Because `Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior` in the words of [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). On a related note, assigning a string literal to a non-const char pointer is deprecated in c++03 and has been disallowed since c++11.

a) You're probably referring to the value returned by the function. A value returned by copy is always an rvalue.

b) The literal `"string"` is of type `const char[7]` and has static storage duration. It is *typically* stored in a read only data segment such as `.rodata` but that's not specified by the language.

Answer (score 0):

a) Function `char* f2()` returns a value (roughly speaking, a number representing a memory address). Is the same of function `char f1()` that returns a value (another number).

Function `char& f3()`, on the other hand, returns a reference to a variable.

b) As Anton Savin pointed out, "string" is a `const char[7]` and for modern compilers (C++11) the first assignment is illegal. The memory location of the first character 's' is easily readable into `ab`.

Comment: `"string"` is `const char[7]`.